# Where should I put a new Sitecore project on my C drive

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, project-management

I am VERY green at Sitecore and I am developing a site from scratch using Sitecore.

I have a few questions on where to start:

1. Should I put the project in C://inetpub/wwwroot/ as I do most of my other projects?

1a: If so, would I run the project in the browser like so:  localhost/mySiteCoreSite/sitecore?  or is there a different way?

(I can not run my code behind through visual studio of course. - I do know about the "w3wp" process that you can run in the back ground from VS2012 and that is what Ive used to debug my code.)

Thank you all.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

I've set it up like this:
- Install Sitecore in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`
- Create a VS project in `c:\projects\sitecore`

I copy the code from my VS project to my Sitecore website using MSBuild.

Regarding your browser question: I usually set up a website in IIS pointing to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` (or wherever Sitecore is installed). Then add an entry in my `hostfile` such as `sitecore.local`, pointing that to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Trakek - your link doesn't appear legitimate... looks like adware or spam, can you fix it or remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Default Sitecore is installing on folder c:\inetpub\wwwroot

There's lots of info for installing Sitecore on the SDN, as well as plenty of tutorials, cookbooks and references. Installation guides: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/Installation.aspx

Sitecore fundamentals: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Developer/Training%20Materials/Fundamentals.aspx

Building a basic site: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Developer/Training%20Materials/Basic%20Site.aspx